# What does $26^\circ 10'$ mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

All of a sudden my PreCalc book started using $26^\circ 10'$ as an angle measure. What does this mean? Specifically, what's going on with the $10'$?

Comment: The circle's divided in 360 degrees, each degree's divided in 60 minutes (the 10'), each minute in 60 seconds....

Comment: Do not stress too much if this certain measure seems hard to deal with. When studying calculus, and advanced precal, radian measures will be utilized mostly, which is an easier measure than degrees,minutes, and seconds.

Comment: @MitchKnight I know...I had just gotten used to radians during the unit circle unit and now we're back in degrees =)

Comment: Minutes and seconds are ${1 \over 60}$ and ${1 \over 3600}$ of a degree respectively, just as with the closely related hours. It is as ingrained as hours, minutes, seconds are for specifying angles, particularly for latitude and longitude. The advantage of a minute of latitude is that it corresponds to one nautical mile, so makes some (pre-cheap computer) calculations rather straightforward. Another unit is the grad if you want more to think about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $$\large{a^{\circ} b' c''}$$

refers to $a$ degrees, $b$ minutes, and $c$ seconds; $1$ second of arc is $1/60$ of a minute of arc, and a minute is $1/60$ of a degree.

Answer (score 2):

$26$ degrees and $10$ minutes.

Comment: That makes me think of latitude/longitude. But that doesn't make sense here, because, as I said, it was an angle measure. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @evamvid it is still an angle measure because $10$ minutes is actually $\frac{10}{60}=\left(\frac16\right) ^{\circ}.$  Add that value to $26^{\circ}$ and you get $\left(26\frac16\right) ^{\circ}$

Comment: @jnh Thanks!  Why do you think in this case they would choose to use minutes instead of straight degrees (even fractional)?

Comment: Latitude, longitude are angles. For example, suppose you are at point $P$ in the northern hemisphere. Let $P'$ be the point on the Equator due South of $P$, and let $C$ be the centre of the Earth. Then the latitude of $P$ is $\angle PCP'$.

Comment: @evamvid Well, I assume that the book is probably trying to teach you about how to convert from minutes to degrees and vice versa.

Comment: @evamvid  Why would they choose to use degrees instead of radians??

Answer (score 2):

So look at it like a mixed number. $26\frac{10}{60}^{\circ}$

Answer (score 2):

The extra $'$ you see is called a *minute*. Technically all angles are written in the form:
$$x^\circ y' z''$$
The $^\circ$ means degrees, as you know. The $'$ is a *minute*, which is $\dfrac{1}{60}$ of a degrees. The $''$ is a *second*, which is $\dfrac{1}{60}$ of a minute. Have you ever looked at world maps and the coordinates of some cities? They often look like this:
$$51^\circ 4' 43'' \ \text{N}, \ 85^\circ 17' 31'' \ \text{W}$$
In your case, $26^\circ 10'$ means this: $26^\circ$ **plus** $\dfrac{10}{60}$ of a degree. So $26^\circ 10'$ can be thought of like $26\frac{10}{60}^\circ$. That equals $26\frac{1}{6}^\circ$. If you want it in decimal form (which I think is easier to understand), $26^\circ 10' = 26.1\bar{6}^\circ$. I hope this post was helpful.